# Actors appearing in both Star Trek and Star Wars?

Tags: star-trek, star-wars, actors

**Are there any actors who appeared in both Star Trek and Star Wars?**

If so, who and how many?

<sub>(All series and films of Star Trek, and both Star Wars trilogies, are included. Upcoming productions such as *The Force Awakens*, for which some cast members have already been announced, are also included.)</sub>

Comment: Actors? My life is a lie.

Comment: So, the SW cartoons are excluded? Uncle George will be so disappointed.

Comment: Title says "**appearing** in", question says "**starred** in". Which is it, and how do you define "star"?

Comment: @user14111 ... what's the difference? I thought they meant the same thing.

Comment: @Randal'Thor "Starring" is a fairly technical term that refers to a particular role or set of roles in a movie. "Appearing in" just means that they were there. Will Wheaton appeared in Star Trek, but he did not have a "Starring role" in any episodes (that I know of).

Comment: @Matt OK, fixed.

Comment: @CandiedMango - The ship was a model, as big as this.  Our nuetronium core was paper mache and christmas lights!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Films

[Simon Pegg](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0670408/) was in the 2009 [*Star Trek*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/) as [Montgomery Scott](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Montgomery_Scott_(alternate_reality)).
He was also in [*Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/) as [Unkar Plutt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unkar_Plutt).

[Deep Roy](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0746989/) was in [*Star Wars: Episode VI – Return of the Jedi*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086190/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_11) as [Droopy McCool](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Droopy_McCool). He was also in the 2009 [*Star Trek*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/) as [Keenser](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Keenser). For an added bonus he was [Mr. Sin](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Mr_Sin) in the 1977 Doctor Who story arc [The Talons of Weng-Chiang](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Talons_of_Weng-Chiang_(TV_story)). Sci-Fi trifecta!

[Felix Silla](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0798061/) played a Talosian in the first pilot for the original series, [The Cage](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cage_(episode)). He also played an Ewok in [*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086190/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_11).

[Christopher Lloyd](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000502/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_3) played [Kruge](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kruge) in Star Trek III, and [Helgait](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Helgait) in the Mandalorian

### EU

In the Expanded Universe of Star Wars we have [Brock Peters](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0676349/) who played [Admiral Cartwright](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cartwright) in [*Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092007/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_48) & [*Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102975/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_37) & [Joseph Sisko](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joseph_Sisko) in [*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106145/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_13) who also voiced Darth Vader in [*Star Wars Radio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio)).

### Cartoon Series

[George Takei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Takei), who played [Hikaru Sulu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hikaru_Sulu) in ToS, was in one episode of [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)), where he voiced [Lok Durd](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lok_Durd).

[Brent Spiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent_Spiner), the man behind [Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data) in TNG, voiced [Gall Trayvis](http://starwarsrebels.wikia.com/wiki/Gall_Trayvis) in [*Star Wars Rebels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels).

[Simon Pegg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Pegg), who played [Montgomery Scott](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Montgomery_Scott) in the 2009 [*Star Trek*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796366/), voiced [Dengar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dengar) in [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)) before he appeared in [*Star Wars: The Force Awakens*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/) in 2015.

[Ian Abercrombie](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000718/) was in 2 episodes of [*Star Trek: Voyager*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112178/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_43) once as [Milo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Milo) and once as [Abbot](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Abbot). He was also the voice for [Emperor Palpatine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) in [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)).

[Olivia d'Abo](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001882/) played [Amanda Rogers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Amanda_Rogers) in [*Star Trek: The Next Generation*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/) and then voiced [Luminara Unduli](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luminara_Unduli) in [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)).

[Brian George](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0313364/) played [Richard Bashir](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/index.php/Richard_Bashir) in [*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106145/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_13) and [Ambassador O’Zaal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/O%27Zaal) in [*Star Trek: Voyager*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112178/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_43). He then voiced [Ki-Adi-Mundi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi) in [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)).

[Ron Perlman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000579/) played [Viceroy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Viceroy_(Reman)) in [*Star Trek: Nemesis*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0253754/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_122) and then voiced [Gha Nachkt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gha_Nachkt) in [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)).

[Sam Witwer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1022429/) played Sloth #3 in [*Star Trek: Enterprise*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244365/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_46) in the episode [The Shipment](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Shipment). He then voiced Darth Maul in [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)) and [Emperor Palpatine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) in [*Star Wars Rebels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels).

### PC Games

Lastly, if you care about [Star Trek: Starfleet Command III, the video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Starfleet_Command_III) then you have [Dee Bradley Baker](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0048389/) who voiced Romulan Officer #2 and then voiced [Captain Rex](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/CT-7567) from [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)).

Comment: Simon Pegg is also rumored to be in the new SW films.

Comment: Felix Silla deserves some sort of special mention: ST, SW, Buck Rogers (Twiki!), a Batman movie, Spaceballs, The Brood, Battlestar Galactica (maybe), the animated Lord of the Rings Movie, Demon Seed, Bewitched, Addams Family...  sheesh!

Comment: "cannon cartoons" lol

Comment: I thought R2-D2 did some crossover work in J.J. Abrams' new Star Trek movies.

Comment: Excellent work! :-)

Comment: "Droopy McCool"? Really?

Comment: SImon Pegg was also in the *Doctor Who* episode "The Long Game".

Comment: Simon Pegg also played C3P0 in Phineas and Ferb Star Wars.  Nowhere near canon, but interesting nevertheless.

Comment: Going to necro this thread and bring up: Dee Bradley Baker is now a voice in canon shows for both now: Prodigy, and Clone Wars/Bad Batch.   Speaking of Bad Batch, the good doctor from DS9 is in season one as a senator. Since you included EU, I just realized one that was forgotten: Daniel Davis was the narrator for Plagueis, and Moriarty.

Answer (score 4):

The most notable actor is Simon Pegg;
as Scotty in the newer Star Trek franchise, he also plays the scrap trader, Unkar Plutt at the start of Star Wars : The Force Awakens, albeit in heavy costume. He's the dude who pays far too few rations for all that hard earned scrap.

Interestingly enough, Simon Pegg is a massive true nerd whose a lover of both Star Wars and Trek so kudos.

Comment: Further to actors being in both Star Wars and Star Trek, Simon Pegg was also in Dr Who appearing as The Editor in "The Long Game" 2005 another added bonus.

Answer (score 3):

You can add Greg Grunberg to that list. He played Commander Finnegan in the [Star Trek Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660888/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3) movies and Snap Wexley in [Star Wars: The Force Awakens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/).

Comment: He also seems to have a credit for the voice of "Stepdad" in Star Trek (2009).  Not sure what that refers to though.

Comment: I think it refers to a deleted scene, when Jim as a child steals the car and we see his stepfather.

Answer (score 1):

- Raphael Sbarge (ST Voyager - KOTOR/KOTOR 2/Republic Commando. All main roles.)
- Jennifer Hale (ST Starfleet Command 3 (predates almost all of the Star Wars work.) - KOTOR/KOTOR 2/TOR. Main roles, she is in a LOT of Star Wars games.)
- Greg Grunberg (Star Trek Beyond - Rogue One.)
- Brian George (ST DS9 (Bashir's father.) - Ki-Adi Mundi in the TCW Series.)
- Clive Revill (ST TNG (Sir Guy of Gisbourne.) - the ORIGINAL Palpatine for ESB. Is arguably the most famous voice for Alfred in the animated series world of Batman.)
- Jason Wingreen (ST TOS (Doctor Linke) - original Boba Fett voice.)
- Patty Maloney (ST Voyager (background role.) - SW Holiday Special. (She played Lumpy, Chewie's son.))
- Clancy Brown (ST ENT (Zobral.) - Savage Opress. Probably one of the most recognisable person on this list. Who was Lex Luthor in the Animated Series, Kurgan in Highlander and Mr and is Mr Krabs in SpongeBob SquarePants.)
- Sam Witwer (ST ENT (background.) - (Do I really need to say this? Darth Maul in TCW/Rebels, Galen Marek and Emperor Palpatine in the Force Unleashed. Just to name three of them.))

There are probably more.